# zf2 read cookie in module class (Module.php)

Tags: cookies, zend-framework2

have set the cookie in my authentication controller now i wan to get/read cookie in my module  class, i have seen the docs to get cookie [ZendHttpCookie getter methods](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.http.cookie.handling.html)
but it does not read the cookie however cookie is created succesfully.
I have created the cookie in the following way

```
$cookie = new SetCookie('name','value', $time); 
$response = $this->getResponse()->getHeaders();
$response->addHeader($cookie);
```

can any one help me to read this cookie in module class

Comment: Can you post the code how you are reading cookies? And you mean in `Module.php`? Also why want to do this?

Comment: i can read it in the controller succesfully but unable to read it in Module.php.
i am doing remember me functionality for my zend authentication.

Comment: Why do you need to read the cookie in the Module ? Module is for bootstraping : load configs and register events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `init` function in `Module.php`

```
public function init(\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager $moduleManager) {
        $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $thatCookie = $request->getHeaders()->get('Cookie')->cookie_name;
        }

}
```

Updated part.
Using remember me.

```
                    if ($request->getPost('rememberme') == 1 ) {
                        $this->getSessionStorage()
                             ->setRememberMe(1);
                        //set storage again 
                        $this->getAuthService()->setStorage($this->getSessionStorage());
                    }
```

Comment: I have use this earlier
request->getHeaders()->get('Cookie')
but it is empty?

Comment: I have used the same code. Try this `echo '<pre>'; print_r($request->getHeaders()->get('Cookie')); die();` and see what happens. Doing this at my side I get `Zend\Http\Header\Cookie Object ( [encodeValue:protected] => 1 [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( [PHPSESSID] => s7b9irq6q9el5qfbveceqij9n1 ) ) ` output and that is fine. Also you can verify by inspecting cookies section of browser developer tools.

Comment: it is empty but when i print the $response object in controller then it returns me the cookie object.(object was set while cookie created in controller)

Comment: Is there any cookie name printed? In my case that is PHPSESSID.

Comment: according to your hint no cookie is being printed

Comment: Then problem is with cookie creation. I think.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47290/discussion-between-shahbaz-and-bilal)

Comment: Ok, By the way why you are not using `rememberMe` method provided by `authStorage`?